# Android databinding - How to get dimensions from dimens.xml

Tags: android, data-binding

I want to set margins based on dimensions i have created in dimens.xml  The dimensions it sself works fine, its just data binding cant find it in the case below:

```
<TextView
           android:id="@+id/title_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/disableButton"
*************
        android:layout_marginBottom="@{@bool/showAds ? 
@dimen/frontpage_margin_ads: @dimen/frontpage_margin_noads}"
*************        
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="64sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

it did find it but it says that marginbottom cannot take type float. How can i fix this? I tried casting both dimens to int but then it complains that it cannot be casted to int.

My dimensions xml file looks like this:

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="bigText">44sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="littleText">44sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="mediumText">40sp</dimen>
        <dimen name="smallText">24sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="fab_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="frontpage_margin_noads">0dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="frontpage_margin_ads">13dp</dimen>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem here is not with dimensions, but with `android:layout_marginBottom`. There is no built-in support for any `LayoutParams` attributes. This was done to remove the "foot gun" that many might use to bind variables to `LayoutParams` and maybe attempt to use data binding to animate their positions this way.

Data Binding is perfect to be used in your example and you can easily add your own. It would be something like this.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_marginBottom")
public static void setBottomMargin(View view, float bottomMargin) {
    MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.setMargins(layoutParams.leftMargin, layoutParams.topMargin,
        layoutParams.rightMargin, Math.round(bottomMargin));
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

You would, of course, also add the left, top, right, start, and end `BindingAdapters` as well.

Comment: Where should I be writing this code? Will all the layouts that I specify marginBottom be using this method or only the data binding ones or this particular layout only?

Comment: You can add this on any (public) class in a project that has data binding enabled. It will be used for all data bound margin attributes.

Comment: The problem is simple: the margin is not the property of the view, but the layout instance of the view. You can do what you tried with other view properties, like padding, but there is a good reason why margin attributes have the prefix `layout_`.

Comment: @GeorgeMount, I found that in AS 2.2 preview 6, I need to set the type of bottomMargin to float instead of int, otherwise I would got compilation error saying that _Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_marginBottom' with parameter type float on android.widget.TextView_

Comment: @GeorgeMount, is it a bug that the parameter expects a float? For fractional dimensions, would we need to add an extra 0.5 to the float value to get the proper int dimension?

Comment: No, it isn't a bug. `@dimen` resources are floats, while `@dimenOffset` and `@dimenSize` are ints. This corresponds to Resources.getDimension(), getDimensionPixelSize(), and getDimensionPixelOffset(), respectively. It is always safe to take a float because ints will automatically convert to floats, but floats won't automatically convert to ints.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeMount you save my day.

Answer (score 2):

Almost the same solution, but using Kotlin:

In file BindingAdapters.kt add:

```
@BindingAdapter("layoutMarginBottom")
fun setLayoutMarginBottom(view: View, dimen: Float) {
    view.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
        bottomMargin = dimen.toInt()
    }
}
```

Usage in layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    app:layoutMarginBottom="@{viewModel.type == Type.SMALL ? @dimen/margin_small : @dimen/margin_large}"
```

You can write similar method for `top`, `start`, `end` margins.

Answer (score 1):

Other examples didn't work for me, so I wrote my own. This can be added to a new, blank Kotlin file. The functions don't need to be in a class. Make sure you've got your own package statement at the top of the file.

```
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.databinding.BindingAdapter

@BindingAdapter("android:layout_marginBottom")
fun setLayoutMarginBottom(view: View, dimen: Int) {
    (view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).let {
        it.bottomMargin = dimen
        view.layoutParams = it
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("android:layout_marginTop")
fun setLayoutMarginTop(view: View, dimen: Int) {
    (view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).let {
        it.topMargin = dimen
        view.layoutParams = it
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("android:layout_marginStart")
fun setLayoutMarginStart(view: View, dimen: Int) {
    (view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).let {
        it.marginStart = dimen
        view.layoutParams = it
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("android:layout_marginEnd")
fun setLayoutMarginEnd(view: View, dimen: Int) {
    (view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).let {
        it.marginEnd = dimen
        view.layoutParams = it
    }
}
```